# Is the space of section of a vector bundle a diffeological space?

Tags: vector-bundles

Let $(E,M,V,\pi)$ be vector bundle over $M$ with fiber $V$ and projection $\pi$.
I am tryng to prove that the space of sections $\Gamma(E)$ of this vector bundle is a diffeological space. I denote the space of plots by $P$.

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set. Given a map $\psi\colon U\times M \rightarrow E$ such that $\pi \circ \psi(u,x)=x$ where $u\in U$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, then for each $u$, $\psi_u(x)=\psi(u,x)$ is a section. So we define a plot $\chi\colon U \rightarrow \Gamma(E)$  by $\chi(u)= \phi_u(x)$.

I am following the book [Diffeology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffeology) for the definition of diffeological space.

Do we have as open cover of the space of sections $\Gamma(E)$ the set of plots $\chi$, that is, for every section $s \in \Gamma(E)$, we should have a plot $\chi \in P$ and $u \in U$ such that $\chi(u)=s$?

Can every section $s \in \Gamma(E)$ be written as  $s(x)= \phi_u(x)$?

Comment: If you have a rank k fibre bundle $E$ over a (finite dimensional) smooth manifold $X$, then the space of sections $\Gamma(E)$ has the structure of a smooth Banach manifold. See Richard Palais Foundations of Global Analysis  https://vmm.math.uci.edu/PalaisPapers/FoundationsOfGlobalNonlinearAnalysis.pdf  for a good exposition or  https://vmm.math.uci.edu/PalaisPapers/BANACHMANIFOLDSOFFIBERBUNDLESECTIONS.pdf  for a proof.

Comment: @Caleb Nastasi Is banach  Manifold a diffeological space

Comment: according to the wiki link you provided in your question, yes.

Comment: You can simply endow $\Gamma(E)$ with the subspace diffeology inherited from the functional space $C^{\infty}(M, E)$.